# how to know when the DOM is ready again after changing URL with window.location.href

Tags: javascript, dom, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing a Firefox extension using Add-on SDK and I successfully scanned a site from a content script and want to go deeper now. However, when I change the url with

```
window.location.href = "http://www.thatsite.com/foo.php";
alert($('#abc');
```

I can't get access to the new DOM. The alert appears before the site is fully read. I tried `$(document).ready(function()` but it seems that this works only once...

How can I wait until the site is fully build?

Comment: What kind of extension? A UserScript? Show more code.

Comment: I just want to find out whether a checkbox on this site is checked.

Comment: @Weedjo: The question is: how do you load that code? Are you using the `page-mod` module of the Add-on SDK? Or do you have a classic extension and run code from an overlay?

Comment: @WladimirPalant: yes, I'm using pageMod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your content script only lives as long as the page is loaded - if you navigate to a different page this content script instance will be unloaded. Another instance of the content script will be loaded into the new page however, you can do everything necessary there. The only problem is passing data from the old instance to the new one. You could send your data to the add-on using `postMessage()` and then have the add-on send it to the new content script in the `onAttach()` handler. Whether this is a possibility in your case depends on what you are trying to achieve (you didn't say that in the question).

Comment: @Weedjo: That's why it is a content script, it works with one page only. If you merely need to a load a page and take a look at it: don't navigate to it, load it into an `<iframe>` element or use `XMLHttpRequest`.

Comment: Thank you Wladimir! I got a perfect idea, because you wrote _"Another instance of the content script will be loaded into the new page..."_ I just checked for `if(window.location.href != "http://www.page1.com")` and so on! and it works perfectly :) Thanks to all of you :)

Comment: but now i realise I'll have a problem with data exchange... hm... any idea?

Comment: I did it with an `<iframe>` and it seems to work quite fine :) thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to move your JS to a higher level if you want to interact with a tab with changing location. See: [MDC docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/On_page_load). As it is, you JS is being applied once within the context of the current page. Once a new page loads, it is effectively non-existent.

Really, you shouldn't be interacting with the page like that from an addon anyways. That's behavior akin to a Greasemonkey userscript, not a Firefox extension.

Comment: It is actually normal behavior for add-ons built with the Add-on SDK, particularly when using `page-mod` module.